# how to add native ads in flutter gridview?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

can someone help me out to add native ads in between the staggedgridview. ads must be shown in between 12 grid of images...can anyone plz help me out....

my code:

```
Container(
                          child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                            mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                            crossAxisCount: 3,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              if (curated.length == 0) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Image.asset("assets/images/empty.gif"),
                                        Text(
                                          "No results found",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.blue),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              } else if (index % 12 == 0) {
                                return Container(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                );
                              } else {
                                if (index < curated.length) {
                                  return ImageTiles(
                                      width: curated[index].width,
                                      height: curated[index].height,
                                      photographerId:
                                          curated[index].photographerId,
                                      url: curated[index].url,
                                      photographerName:
                                          curated[index].photographerName,
                                      photographerUrl:
                                          curated[index].photographerUrl,
                                      original: curated[index].original,
                                      large2x: curated[index].large2x,
                                      large: curated[index].large2x,
                                      medium: curated[index].medium,
                                      small: curated[index].small,
                                      portrait: curated[index].portrait,
                                      landscape: curated[index].landscape,
                                      tiny: curated[index].tiny);
                                } else {
                                  return Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                      child: RaisedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          loadMoreImages(nextPageURL);
                                        },
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                        child: Ink(
                                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                                colors: [
                                                  Colors.redAccent,
                                                  Colors.indigoAccent
                                                ]),
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(80.0)),
                                          ),
                                          child: Container(
                                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                                minWidth: 88.0,
                                                minHeight:
                                                    36.0), // min sizes for Material buttons
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            child: const Text(
                                              'Load More',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 18),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
                              if (index < curated.length)
                                return StaggeredTile.count(
                                    1, index.isEven ? 1.52 : 1.52);
                              else if (index % 12 == 0 && index != 0)
                                return StaggeredTile.count(3, 0.6);
                              else
                                return StaggeredTile.count(3, 0.6);
                            },
                            itemCount: curated.length + 1,
                          ),
                        )
```

can someone help me out to add native ads in between the staggedgridview. ads must be shown in between 12 grid of images...can anyone plz help me out....

[I'm looking to build like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBXfZ.png)